# Checking if a place is OPEN or CLOSED with facebook graph hours

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook graph api and I got the following JSON data:

```
"hours": {
      "mon_1_open": "21:00",
      "mon_1_close": "05:00",
      "tue_1_open": "21:00",
      "tue_1_close": "05:00",
      "wed_1_open": "21:00",
      "wed_1_close": "05:00",
      "thu_1_open": "21:00",
      "thu_1_close": "05:00",
      "fri_1_open": "21:00",
      "fri_1_close": "05:00",
      "sat_1_open": "21:00",
      "sat_1_close": "05:00",
      "sun_1_open": "21:00",
      "sun_1_close": "05:00"
   }
```

I'm using PHP to fetch my info and I can't think of a way to check if this (and other places) are open or closed via the above JSON data.

All I've dont so far is changing the above data to:

Monday: 21:00 - 05:00

Tue: 21:00 - 05:00

etc..

Anyone has any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might give you an idea:

```
<?php
$jd = cal_to_jd(CAL_GREGORIAN,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y"));
$presentday = jddayofweek($jd,1);

$opentime = "";
$closetime = "";

switch($presentday) {

    case 'Monday':
    $opentime = date("g:i a", strtotime($hour_mon_open));
    $closetime = date("g:i a", strtotime($hour_mon_close));
    break;

    case 'Tuesday':
    $opentime = date("g:i a", strtotime($hour_tue_open));
    $closetime = date("g:i a", strtotime($hour_tue_close));    
    break;

    case 'Wednesday':
    $opentime = date("g:i a", strtotime($hour_wed_open));
    $closetime = date("g:i a", strtotime($hour_wed_close));
    break;

    case 'Thursday':
    $opentime = date("g:i a", strtotime($hour_thu_open));
    $closetime = date("g:i a", strtotime($hour_thu_close));
    break;

    case 'Friday':
    $opentime = date("g:i a", strtotime($hour_fri_open));
    $closetime = date("g:i a", strtotime($hour_fri_close));
    break;

    case 'Saturday':
    $opentime = date("g:i a", strtotime($hour_sat_open));
    $closetime = date("g:i a", strtotime($hour_sat_close));
    break;

    case 'Sunday':
    $opentime = date("g:i a", strtotime($hour_sun_open));
    $closetime = date("g:i a", strtotime($hour_sun_close));
    break;

    default:
    break;        
}

$currentHours = date("g:i a", time());
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $currentHours);
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $opentime);
$date3 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $closetime);

if ($date1 > $date2 && $date1 < $date3) {
    echo "Open now";
} else {
    echo "Closed now";
}
?>
```

Hope that helps :)